# Using Generics in Matrix Addition/Multiplication

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a custom class the creates matrices and, among other things, performs operations that add up all of the cells or multiply them all. However, I want to use generics so the matrices can be any type of number: float, double, int, etc. I have thus set up the class like this:

```
public class Matrix<num>
```

Upon initialization, the instantiation of this class creates a matrix based on user supplied data, stored in the instance's .matrix variable. Now, in the code where I want to add up all of the cells, I do something like this:

```
public num addMatrices(num[][] toAdd){
        num result;
        if (toAdd.length != this.rows && toAdd[0].length != this.columns){
            System.out.println("Matrix mismatch. Try Again.");
            return toAdd[0][0];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<rows; j++){
                result = this.matrix[i][j] + toAdd[i][j];
            }
    }
```

I'm running into multiple problems, however. First of all, I can't initialize result to zero, which makes it hard to perform += operations. Secondly, when I try to add the cells of the two matrices, the compiler tells me that the + operator is undefined for the type num.

I thought the whole point of generics was to have a catchall type so I could do things like use floats in one case and ints in another, but if I need to specify the type for operators like +, I'm not sure where the advantage comes in...

Comment: As you only do addition or any kinda arthematic operators i would suggest you to use wildcards with upperbounds. i.e., you could make your class declaration as such 'public class Matrix<Num extends Number> {
'

Comment: @PremGenError note that the abstract class `Number` doesn't have much to it, it's mostly an interface to get the value out of the Object versions of the primitive types.  would specifying that `Num extends Number` enable autoboxing?

Comment: @PeterElliott what i meant was, as arthemetic ops are only done for number types, OP doesn't need to have a custom type defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform operations like `+` and `-` on Objects (some special cases excluded).  Generics are all about Object types, so your use case for them isn't ideal.

That said, you can turn your declaration into something like `public class Matrix<num extends Number>`, which will let you pass in `Integer`, `Double`, `BigInteger`, etc.  then you can then use something like `num.longValue()` or `num.doubleValue()` to get the long or double representations of your numbers.  You would then need to return a `double` or `long` or whatever from your method instead of your generic type, though.

the other option would be to create a custom container class that has methods for add, subtract, etc.  Then your class declaration can be `public class Matrix<num extends Custom>`.  You would have to figure out how to account for adding longs to doubles and returning the Custom type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you `num` can be anything. So, for example, what would it need to do if you created a `Matrix<Object>`?

You could try to make your number extend from [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), but even then you won't be able to use `+` because java don't know what to cast this generic to.

You could create a method similar to your `Matrix` with generic that does that. Something like

```
public static <NUM extends Number> NUM add(NUM[][] matrixA, NUM[][] matrixB, NumFunction<NUM> function) {
    // all equals to your add method, but the result you get with
    result = function.apply(this.matrix[i][j], toAdd[i][j]);
}

public interface NumFunction<NUM extends Number> {
    NUM apply(NUM operA, NUM operB);
}
```

You will need to duplicate `NumFunction` to every type of `Number`, or create one generic that checks what type of Number is with "instanceof". It's not very pretty :P